# Having problems logging in into a new Postgre installation

Tags: postgresql

I just started taking a course which includes PostgreSQL. I am running Windows10 x64 on my machine.

I installed Postgre with the graphical installer. After having to solve many problems (like could not bind IPv4 address, commands not being recognized in CMD, so on) now I can't log into psql.

I am writing psql and I'm getting this error after I enter the password:

```
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "Octavian"
```

and I don't get why. I tried to enter the password that I was asked for when installing postgres and also the one for my windows user.

psql -U postgres works though. (it doesn't even prompt for an answer)

Am I doing something wrong? If not, how can I reset the password? (I tried with ALTER when logging in with -U postgres, but it doesn't change, and I get no error).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please, can you edit your answer with the command used that gave:

```
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "Octavian"
```

By default, Postgresql try to connect via socket, we need to specify -h  when the user is different than **postgres**.
Imagine that I made a fresh installation, connecting with "psql -U postgres":

```
psql -U postgres
postgres=# CREATE USER elvis PASSWORD 'aloha';
postgres=# \q
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U elvis postgres
Password for user elvis: *****
postgres=> \q
psql -U postgres
postgres=# ALTER USER elvis WITH PASSWORD '123';
postgres=# \q
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U elvis postgres
Password for user elvis: ***
postgres=> SELECT 'It should work';
```

Comment: THANK YOU!  This is the correct answer. Also: why TF is psql by default trying to connect to a user that in 9/10 cases does not exist?

Comment: Maybe because the focus is Linux, when we install Postgres from packages - by far the most common method - the user is added automatically. Postgres for Windows is relatively new compared with the Linux version.

Answer (score 0):

Use the client with postgres user:

```
sudo su - postgres
```

Once inside postgres user, type:

```
psql
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).